# Different class to every second post in WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I researched a whole web, and the solution for assigning different class to every 2nd post in blog view in WordPress was adding below code into ***function.php***. Most people claim it is helpful, but to me it just adds ***odd*** at the end of the post class. There is no **even** class anywhere.

```
function alternating_post_class($classes) {
    global $wp_query;
    $classes[] = ( $wp_query->current_post%2 === 0 ? 'odd' : 'even' );
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'alternating_post_class');
```

What have I done wrong? It is suposed to add odd class to my first blog post, then even class for my second post in the blog view, but the result is as I said always the same: odd.

Comment: Have you tried swapping the 'odd' and 'even'?

Comment: Then it displays only 'even' in the post classes. :(

Comment: Throw a `print $wp_query->current_post; // debug` in there to see what's getting compared to `% (mod) 2`.

Comment: An even_number mod 2 equals 0, and an odd_number mod 2 does not.

Comment: When I put print $wp_query it returns number 1 everywhere. Instead of 1, 2, 3, 4...